# How to use socket.io service in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, sockets, socket.io

I am new in sockets, so i am implementing `socket.io` services in angular project..?

How to Use Sockets in Angular?

May be using some cool `Socket.io` Examples?

Libraries? Tutorials? Blog Articles?

Comment: I've been using WS in this project https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync

Answer (score 7):

**How to use socket service in angular 6?**

**1.First you have to create component in angular like :**

**socketComponent.ts**

```
import { SocketDataService } from 'socketDataService';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-socket',
  templateUrl: './app-socket.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-socket.component.css'],

})

export class SocketComponent implements OnInit {


  sub: Subscription;

  constructor(private socketDataService: SocketDataService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.getSocketData();
    }

    getSocketData(): void {
    this.sub = this.socketDataService.getSocketData()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.socketData = data
    })
  }
}
```

**2. You have to create service like :**

**socketService.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class SocketDataService {

    private socket;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000')
    }

    observer
    getSocketData(): Observable<any> {
        this.socket.on('socket-data', (res) => {
            this.observer.next(res);
        });
        return this.getSocketDataObservable();
    }
    getSocketDataObservable(): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable(observer => {
            this.observer = observer;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for code its helpful for me...